# Download Excel File with Custom Headers..I face this Problem

Tags: javascript, angularjs, xls

I,m exporting(downloading) an excel file for client user, That the the user enter their data according to the corresponding headers of an excel, after that the system accept the user data when the user upload the excel to the system... The headers is downloaded successfully but in single column in comma between. i need that each header is in a unique single column like below  [image]

but i need like this[image]
and this is my code...

```
$scope.DownLoadTemplate = function () {

    for (a in $scope.SalaryHeadList)
    {
        $scope.HeadTitle = $scope.SalaryHeadList[a].Title;
        $scope.HeaderList.push(angular.copy($scope.HeadTitle));
    }
    $scope.CurrencyTitle = $scope.CurrencyList[0].Title;
    $scope.HeaderList.push(angular.copy($scope.CurrencyTitle));

    var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([$scope.HeaderList]));
    var link = document.createElement('a');
    var filename = "Employee.xls";
    link.href = url;
    link.setAttribute('download', filename);
    document.body.appendChild(link);
    link.click();
}
```

please help!

Answer (score 0):

```
$scope.exportData = function () {
    debugger;
    var uri = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,'
        , template = `
             <html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" 
                   xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel"
                   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
               <head>
                 <!--[if gte mso 9]>
                    <xml>
                      <x:ExcelWorkbook>
                        <x:ExcelWorksheets>
                          <x:ExcelWorksheet>
                            <x:Name>{CouponDetails}</x:Name>
                            <x:WorksheetOptions>
                              <x:DisplayGridlines/>
                            </x:WorksheetOptions>
                          </x:ExcelWorksheet>
                        </x:ExcelWorksheets>
                      </x:ExcelWorkbook>
                    </xml>
                  <![endif]-->
                </head>
                <body><table>{table}</table></body>
              </html>
            `
        , base64 = function (s) { return window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s))) }
        , format = function (s, c) { return s.replace(/{(\w+)}/g, function (m, p) { return c[p]; }) }

    var table = document.getElementById("example1");
    var ctx = { worksheet: name || 'Worksheet', table: table.innerHTML };
    var url = uri + base64(format(template, ctx));
    var a = document.createElement('a');
    a.href = url;
    a.download = 'Expoerdata.xls';
    a.click();
};
```

HTML table:

```html
<table id="example1" class="table table-bordered invoice-custom example1" 
       style="display:none;">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th data-field="id">Sno</th>
            <th data-field="name" data-editable="true">Name</th>

            <th data-field="phone" data-editable="true">Value</th>

            <th data-field="action">Edit</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="Test in allItems | orderBy:TestParams_Id:reverse">
            <td style="text-align:center">
                {{Test.sno}}
            </td>
            <td>{{Test.Name}}</td>
            <td>{{Test.ExpectedValue}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: thanks...its working But my headers on excel goes to second row....

Comment: @georgeawg ...It Not Working Properly. when i add some data in it its give me a message as   "some features in your workbook might be lost if you save it as web page" and create a new folder having html files ... while the original downloaded excel become an empty excel file (all the headers are erased)